# How do I initialize my script so I don't get a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm sure I'm missing something basic since I don't use ruby that much.

I have this class (truncated for simplicity):

```
require 'koala'
require 'time'
class FBRank
    def initialize_with(access_token, photo_rank_weight=150, link_rank_weight=30, post_rank_weight=140, tagged_rank_weight=70, liked_photo_weight=150)
        puts "hello?"
        @graph_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
        @photo_rank_weight = photo_rank_weight
        @link_rank_weight = link_rank_weight        
        @post_rank_weight  = post_rank_weight
        @tagged_rank_weight = tagged_rank_weight
        @liked_photo_weight = liked_photo_weight
    end
end
```

Then I:

```
:young-waters-3693[104] > irb
1.9.3p429 :002 > require './ranking'
1.9.3p429 :002 > FBRank.initialize_with('CAAJzb7....')
NoMethodError: undefined method `initialize_with' for FBRank:Class
```

What have I not instantiated correctly? I tried creating an object that is an instance of this class but that didn't work either, but that could have been because I did it wrong...

Comment: Don't use `initialize_with`, stick with `initialize`, so you can use the normal `new` as your initializer. It's the Ruby convention, it's how the language was designed to work, and it works as well as using `initialize_with` or better since EVERYTHING in the Ruby eco-system will work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class methods are defined by prepending `self.`:

```
class FBRank
  def self.initialize_with(...)
  end
end
```

However, you should return an instance, something like:

```
def self.initialize_with(access_token, photo_rank_weight=150, link_rank_weight=30, post_rank_weight=140, tagged_rank_weight=70, liked_photo_weight=150)
  rank = FBRank.new
  rank.access_token = access_token
  # ...
  rank
end
```

Or even better use Ruby's `initialize` method:

```
def initialize(access_token, photo_rank_weight=150, link_rank_weight=30, post_rank_weight=140, tagged_rank_weight=70, liked_photo_weight=150)
  @access_token = access_token
  # ...
end
```

You can then create a `FBRank` instance with:

```
FBRank.new('CAAJzb7', 150, 30, 140, 70, 150)
```

It might also be a good idea to use a hash for passing the options:

```
def initialize(access_token, options={})
  @access_token = access_token
  @photo_rank_weight = options.fetch(:photo_rank_weight, 150)
  @link_rank_weight = options.fetch(:link_rank_weight, 30)
  @post_rank_weight = options.fetch(:post_rank_weight, 140)
  @tagged_rank_weight = options.fetch(:tagged_rank_weight, 70)
  @liked_photo_weight = options.fetch(:liked_photo_weight, 150)
end
```

and initialize it via:

```
FBRank.new('CAAJzb7',
           photo_rank_weight: 150,
           link_rank_weight: 30,
           post_rank_weight: 140,
           tagged_rank_weight: 70,
           liked_photo_weight: 150)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling an instance method from the Class itself which is why you're getting no method error. If you're trying to set it up with an `initialize_with` to prep an instance then you should change this:

```
FBRank.initialize_with('CAAJzb7....')
```

to this:

```
FBRank.new.initialize_with('CAAJzb7....')
```

Calling new creates a new FBRank instance and then you use your `initialize_with` to configure the instance variables; however, you would not be able to chain this call and assign a variable like this unless you set `initialize_with` to return `self` at the end.

Although, creating your own initialize seems kind of pointless, just use `def initialize` and then you pass your arguments to `new`. After all that is the point of the initialize block is to prepare an instance for use.

```
FBRank.new('CAAJzb7....')
```